# How to handle exceptions in methods running asynchronous?

Tags: c#, mysql, task, background-process

I'm building a program that keeps track of a directory and adds an entry to an mysql database whenever a new file has been created in the directory. A while ago I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430206/can-you-make-your-program-do-other-things-while-waiting-for-the-filesystemwatche) for how to let the class FileSystemWatcher run independently while filling a backgroundqueue of actions to process, while the FileSystemWatcher keeps searching. I got a solution for that, but would like to ask a follow up question. First of all, here is the code:

This is the constructor for the watcher

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = directoryToWatch,
    IncludeSubdirectories = true,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                   NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                   NotifyFilters.FileName,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    Filter = "*.*"
};

watcher.Created += (OnDirectoryChange);
```

Here is the OnDirectoryChange method:

```
public void OnDirectoryChange(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bq.QueueTask(() => storage.Insert(Settings.Default.added_files, e.Name));
    }
    catch (StorageException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        HandleException(se, se.Filename, se.Number);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch all exceptions");
    }
}
```

The HandleException method:

```
public void HandleException(Exception exceptionToHandle, string fileName = "empty", int number = 0)
{
    try
    {
        if (number < Acceptedammountofexceptions)
        {
            AddExceptionToStack(exceptionToHandle, fileName);
            RetryFailedFiles(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(fileName, number));
        }
        else if (number >= Acceptedammountofexceptions)
        {
            AddExceptionToCriticalList(exceptionToHandle, fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, couldnt insert this file. See the log for more information.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in HandleException");
        throw;
    }
}
```

The RetryFailedFiles method:

```
public void RetryFailedFiles(KeyValuePair<string, int> file)
{
    int count = file.Value + 1;
    try
    {
        bq.QueueTask(() => storage.Insert(Settings.Default.added_files, file.Key));
    }
    catch (StorageException se)
    {
        HandleException(se, file.Key, count);
        Console.WriteLine(se);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to retry inserting failed files a certain amount of tries. However, the failed file will not be retried at this moment. I'm feeling a bit lost in my own program to be honest. If it helps, here is the code for the insert statement.

```
public Task Insert(string tablename, string filename, int number=0)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " (FILE_NAME, " +
                       "Id) VALUES('" + filename + "', '" + Id + "')";

        using (MySqlConnection insertConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            insertConn.Open();
            if (insertConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MySqlCommand insertCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, insertConn) {CommandType = CommandType.Text};
                while (insertCmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    // Spinlock
                }

                insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                insertConn.Close();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            StorageException se = new StorageException("Couldn't connect to database!", filename, number);
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
            return Task.FromException(se);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("duplicate"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already exists", "Duplicate entry", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            StorageException se = new StorageException(ex.Message, filename, number);
            Console.WriteLine("Well");
            return Task.FromException(se);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I was already trying to get an exception, but I can't seem to trace it, if that makes sense.

So how would I go and handle the exceptions thrown to make sure the filenames will be tried again when they failed the first time?

Edit:
Backgroundqueue class:

```
public class BackgroundQueue
{
    private Task previousTask = Task.FromResult(true);
    private object key = new object();
    public Task QueueTask(Action action)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            previousTask = previousTask.ContinueWith(t => action()
                , CancellationToken.None
                , TaskContinuationOptions.None
                , TaskScheduler.Default);
            return previousTask;
        }
    }

    public Task<T> QueueTask<T>(Func<T> work)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            var task = previousTask.ContinueWith(t => work()
                , CancellationToken.None
                , TaskContinuationOptions.None
                , TaskScheduler.Default);
            previousTask = task;
            return task;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: genuine question: *why* does that method return `Task`? it doesn't seem to actually do anything "async" - is this simply to meet a required interface? does `MySqlCommand` not support "async" methods?

Comment: also: obligatory "please please please" don't concatenate values into SQL; that is a huge security risk, that is trivially mitigated using parameters - see "SQL injection"

Comment: If you want to throw an exception, you should probably use `throw`.  It might be that, although that will fix your problem, throwing and handling exceptions is not the best way to control the flow of your code

Comment: I changed the method to not have task in it anymore, and it still works. It was probably from the last time I asked a question, while I was trying different stuff out. The SQL injection is stuff I will change in a future stadium, I'm first focussing on the main functionalities and exception handling now. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: @pm_2 that may be a moot point; I expect `insertConn.Open();` will do the throw you describe *anyway*, so the `StorageException` will never be reached

Comment: @pm_2 What would be the best way to control the flow? I use these for when the database connection is gone while the program is executing. (It is a background service)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what `bq` is, but I'm guessing that it is essentially a wrapper around a `Queue<Func<Task>>` - i.e. a queue of things that *when invoked* start an async operation. If that is the case, then your work loop should (if it intends to preserve order) do something like:

```
async Task RunQueue() {
    while(keepGoing) {
        if(no work) await work; // somehow, not shown; needs to be thread-safe

        Func<Task> nextAction = queue.ThreadSafeDequeue();
        try {
            await nextAction();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            DoSomethingUseful(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing is the `await` which waits for the async completion, and re-raises any exception observed.

However, note that *in your specific case*, the `Insert` work being done *is not* actually async - it will always complete (or fail) synchronously. This *isn't necessarily* a problem, but: data access like this is a prime candidate for async.

Comment: @Superleggera that's... hmmm, wow; *why* are you doing that? you seem to be manually implementing a continuation strategy that is basically the same as `await`, but without all the things that make `await` great. It really isn't clear to me what you're trying to do there, or why...

Comment: Well it came from my previous problem. The queue did what it had to do. However you tell me now there is a simpler and greater way? I'm sorry, didn't have to look into async, await, tasks or threads yet so I'm pretty new to it.